# How to attach a file to a fossil ticket

Tags: fossil

The title just about says it all.

I found a similar question on the fossil-users mailing list, and Richard Hipp responded [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/fossil-users@lists.fossil-scm.org/msg17997.html) saying just to add the "b" capability for the user. As the user in question had "s", I thought this was unnecessary, but it would have been rude not to try, which I did. I still can't see any way to add an attachment.

I'm using [chiselapp](http://chiselapp.com) and I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious. If someone could steer me to what that something is, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Do you mean at the point of creation? You can attach stuff to a ticket that's already been created (there's an "Attach" link at the top-left of the page when you view the ticket) but I don't think you can do it (create a ticket with an attachment) in a single action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach files to a ticket that's already been created (there's an "Attach" link at the top-left of the page when you view the ticket) but I don't think you can do it (create a ticket with an attachment) in a single action.

Comment: Thanks. That was the obvious thing I was missing.